# Printing a line with a variable number that the user writes

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to solve a problem about reading a variable in bash with awk.

In bash, I have something like this:

```
echo "Please, write a number"
read number
awk '{if($1 == "number") print $1,$2}' $1
```

My file is something like this:

```
34 hello
56 bye
76 my
81 name
91 is
```

I would like that when someone write a number, for example 34 in the terminal I will see:
34 hello.

However, this is not happening, and I don't know where is the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something like `awk -v number=$number '$1 == number' file`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Wiktor Stribiżew